# Detect software uninstallation on Windows

Tags: windows, logging, uninstallation

I would like to log the uninstall event onto my own web-server for my desktop application. Is there a way I can detect the uninstallation on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your installer override the Installer.OnAfterUninstall method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.onafteruninstall(v=vs.100).aspx

There, you can call back to your web server.

Be sure to program for the possibility that there is no internet connection at the time of uninstall.  Also, note that some firewalls may block your attempt to connect to your server from the uninstall program, or prompt the user for permission to allow the connection.

If you are using an installer other than Microsoft's (e.g. NSIS or whatever) for the desktop application, there is probably a similar hook.